# Proof that a given function is not a OWF

Tags: one-way-function

I'm currently learning about one-way functions. I have a book with the following exercise (Sadly there is no solution in the book...)

> Let $g\colon \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$ be a one way function.
>   Prove that $f\colon \{0,1\}^{2n} \to \{0,1\}^n$ with $f(v,w) := g(v)⊕w$  is NOT a one way function.

I don't really get how I can solve this exercise... because if $w$ is, for example, $0^n$, it would be a simple reduction to show that it is in fact a one-way function, right?

How can I get an advantage $>\mathit{negligible}(n)$ ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64344/discussion-on-question-by-flo-proof-that-a-given-function-is-not-a-owf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attacker is given $y = f(v,w)$ and must find $v$ and $w$. The attacker can generate a random $v_0$ and calculate $g(v_0)$; then they can simply calculate $w_0=y⊕g(v_0)$ and then return $(v_0,w_0)$, for which $f(v_0,w_0)=y  \implies \Pr[\mathit{Invert}=1]=1>\mathit{negl}(n)$.